# iPhone : OpenGL ES : Detecting if you have tapped a object (cube) on screen

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, picking

I asked a similar question already which got me to where I am now but I really need some help on this one.  Its the last thing in my way to completing something cool (in my eyes lol)

I have a 3d world where I can move around and in this world are simple cubes.

Using the function -(CGPoint)getScreenCoorOfPoint:(IMPoint3D)_point3D I can work out where these cubes are in X,Y within the 3D world.  But its not based on where I am but where they are with the 3d Area.  Using the same function, I can also work out where I am.  Also I can find out where someone has tapped on the screen.

How on earth do I map these together so that I can work out if I have clicked one of them?

Surely I need something to work out which way I am facing.  People have suggested rendering them off screen and doing something but it went completely over my head.  I think of scrapping the function about and building my own based on the 3d coords (somehow)

Code

```
for (NSDictionary *item in self.players)
{
    int x;
    int z;

    x =  [[item objectForKey:@"posX"] floatValue];
    z =  [[item objectForKey:@"posZ"] floatValue];

    IMPoint3D playerPos;
    playerPos.x = x;
    playerPos.z = z;
    playerPos.y = 1;

    CGPoint screenPositionOfThisCube  ; 
    screenPositionOfThisCube = [self getScreenCoorOfPoint:playerPos];


    #define TUNE 28
    CGRect fingerSquish = CGRectMake(
                                     screenPositionOfThisCube.x - TUNE,
                                     screenPositionOfThisCube.y - TUNE,
                                     TUNE * 2,
                                     TUNE * 2);

    // now check that the POINT OF THE TOUCH
    // is inside the rect fingerSquish

    if ( CGRectContainsPoint( fingerSquish, pos ) )
    {
        NSLog(@"WOOP");
        // YOU HAVE FOUND THE TOUCHED CUBEY.
        // YOU ARE DONE.  this item is the cube being touched.
        // make the cube change color or something to test it.
    }
}
```

I also trying out gluUnproject with no success (see my other post)

[image]

Comment: SOURCE can be found here http://burf.org.uk/Moving3d.zip

Comment: Really I do apogiles mate, please please help me solve this.  I tried to even set a bounty so you get my points

Comment: Hi Joe.  I know posY is 1 because its hardcoded : glTranslatef(x, 1 , z);  The array does not include Y because it is hardcoded.  I just clicked on each corner of a few squares and the code does not work.  Sorry .  It only seems to trigger one of the 4 squares if I don't move or rotate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notion which you're discussing (selecting object on a 3D screen by 2D coords) is referred to as **picking**.

See my older posts for some solutions:

[How would you solve this opengl necessity (in c) involving knowing in which square in a boardgame did the user click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199358/how-would-you-solve-this-opengl-necessity-in-c-involving-knowing-in-which-squar/4203754#4203754)

[OpenGL GL_SELECT or manual collision detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040616/opengl-gl-select-or-manual-collision-detection/4059685#4059685)

Comment: I don't think Kos has a solution for me as he has answered other posts on the same subject for me

Comment: The latter answer describes the color picking, which is the method I recommend for you. I was about to describe another method with occlusion queries, but then I noticed than OpenGL ES doesn't support OQ (for some reasons unknown to me...), so that wouldn't be helpful in your case.

Comment: How do I actually render stuff at 1px and a small viewport then, just tried out glPickColour and yeah would work but now need to know how render everything twice

Comment: **Scissor test** is used to limit the rendering to a single pixel. Never heard of `glPickColour` btw, what's that?

Comment: Well initial test show it returns the colour of an object on screen so you render everything different collies then rerender the proper view.  I nearly got something working but getting odd results when 2 objects are near

Comment: Sorry I mean glReadPixels, Kos have you used that

Comment: So what's the problem with rendering the scene the second time with different colours?

Answer (score 1):

I thought I post the main class

```
#import "GLViewController.h" 
#import "ConstantsAndMacros.h" 
#import "OpenGLCommon.h"
#import "WorldAppDelegate.h"
#import "Tools.h"
#import "glu.h"

#define SPEED_MOVE 0.025 
#define SPEED_TURN 0.05
#define MapSizeX 20
#define MapSizeZ 20

typedef struct 
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} IMPoint3D;

@interface GLViewController ()

- (void)updateData;
- (BOOL)checkCollisionWithX:(float)x andWithZ:(float)z;
- (void)loadTextures:(NSString *)textureName andWithIndex:(int)index;
- (void)handleTouches;
- (void)updateCoords;
- (void)setupPlayer;
- (void)addScene;
- (void)loadTextureList;
- (void)loadController;
- (Boolean) checkCollission:(CGPoint)winPos object:(IMPoint3D) _object;
- (CGPoint)getScreenCoorOfPoint:(IMPoint3D)_point3D;
@end

@implementation GLViewController

@synthesize deviceID, players, label,collisionArray, baseURL;

-(void)setupView:(GLView*)view { 

    const GLfloat zNear = 0.1, zFar = 1000.0, fieldOfView = 120.0; 
    GLfloat size = zNear * tanf(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(fieldOfView) / 8.0);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    //Rotate the view
    glRotatef(-90,0,0,1);

    CGRect rect = self.view.bounds; 
    glFrustumf(-size, size, -size / (rect.size.width / rect.size.height), size / (rect.size.width / rect.size.height), zNear, zFar);

    glViewport(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

    // Starting position
    eye[0] = -0; 
    eye[1] = 3;
    eye[2] = -10; 
    center[0] = 0; 
    center[1] = 1.5;
    center[2] = 0;

    [self loadTextureList];
    [self loadController];
    [self loadTextureList ];
    [self addScene];    
    [self setupPlayer];
    [self updateCoords]; 

} 


// ...
- (void)drawView:(UIView *)theView { 

    // floor
    const GLfloat floorVertices[] = { 
        -1, 0.0f, 1,
        1, 0.0f, 1,
        1, 0.0f, -1, 
        -1, 0.0f, -1
        };

    const GLshort floorTextureCoords[] = {
        0, 1, // top left
        0, 0, // bottom left
        1, 0, //bottom right
        1, 1  //top right
    };

    // Colour cube
    static const GLubyte cubeNumberOfIndices = 36;

    const GLubyte colourCubeFaceColors[] = {
        0,255,0,255,
        255,125,0,255,
        255,0,0,255,
        255,255,0,255,
        0,0,255,255,
        255,0,255,255
    };


    static const Vertex3D texturedVertices[]= {
        {-1.0, 1.0, 1.0},             // vertices[0]
        {1.0, 1.0, 1.0},              // vertices[1]
        {-1.0, -1.0, 1.0},             // vertices[2]
        {-1.0, -1.0, 1.0},            // vertices[3]
        {1.0, 1.0, 1.0},             // vertices[4]
        {1.0, -1.0, 1.0},             // vertices[5]
        {-1.0, 1.0, 1.0},              // vertices[6]
        {-1.0, 1.0, -1.0},             // vertices[7]
        {-1.0, -1.0, 1.0},            // vertices[8]
        {-1.0, -1.0, 1.0},            // vertices[9]
        {-1.0, 1.0, -1.0},             // vertices[10]
        {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0},         // vertices[11]
        {-1.0, 1.0, -1.0},             // vertices[12]
        {1.0, 1.0, -1.0},              // vertices[13]
        {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0},             // vertices[14]
        {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0},            // vertices[15]
        {1.0, 1.0, -1.0},             // vertices[16]
        {1.0, -1.0, -1.0}, 
        {1.0, 1.0, 1.0},
        {1.0, 1.0, -1.0},
        {1.0, -1.0, 1.0},
        {1.0, -1.0, 1.0},
        {1.0, 1.0, -1.0},
        {1.0, -1.0, -1.0},
        {-1.0, 1.0, 1.0},
        {-1.0, 1.0, -1.0},
        {1.0, 1.0, 1.0},
        {1.0, 1.0, 1.0},
        {-1.0, 1.0, -1.0},
        {1.0, 1.0, -1.0},
        {-1.0, -1.0, 1.0},
        {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0},
        {1.0, -1.0, 1.0},
        {1.0, -1.0, 1.0},
        {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0},
        {1.0, -1.0, -1.0},
    };

    static const GLubyte texturedCube[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        3, 4, 5,
        6, 7, 8,
        9, 10, 11,
        12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17,
        18, 19, 20,
        21, 22, 23,
        24, 25, 26, 
        27, 28, 29,
        30, 31, 32, 
        33, 34, 35,
    };

    static const GLfloat texturedCubeCoord[] = {
        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0,

        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,

        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,

        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0,

        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0,

        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0,

    };


    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);


    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    [self handleTouches];

    //view : prebaked in to OPenGL Template
    gluLookAt(eye[0], eye[1], eye[2],center[0],  center[1], center[2], 0.0, 1, 0.0);

    // draw the floor
    glPushMatrix();

    //tell GL about our texture 
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glScalef(20,20,1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glScalef(20,1,20);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_SHORT, 0, floorTextureCoords);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, floorVertices); 
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);

    glPopMatrix();

    for (NSString *coords in self.collisionArray) {

        NSArray *coordsArray = [coords componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        float x =  [[coordsArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue] ;
        float z =  [[coordsArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] ;
        float width =  ([[coordsArray objectAtIndex:2] floatValue] /2) ;
        float length =   ([[coordsArray objectAtIndex:3] floatValue] /2) ;

        glPushMatrix();

        //tell GL about our texture
        glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
        glLoadIdentity();

        if (width > length) {
            glScalef(width, 3, length);
        } else {
            glScalef(length, 3, width);
        }

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ([[coordsArray objectAtIndex:4] floatValue]));
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glTranslatef(x, 3, z);
        glScalef(width, 3, length);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, texturedVertices);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texturedCubeCoord);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,cubeNumberOfIndices , GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texturedCube);

        glPopMatrix();
    }

    float x;
    float z;
    float playerRotation;

    for (NSDictionary *item in self.players) {

        x = [[item objectForKey:@"posX"] floatValue];
        z = [[item objectForKey:@"posZ"] floatValue];
        playerRotation = [[item objectForKey:@"rotation"] floatValue];

        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(x, 1 , z);
        glRotatef(playerRotation, 0, 1, 0);


        //Reset textures
        glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
        glLoadIdentity();

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, texturedVertices);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texturedCubeCoord);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &texturedCube[0]);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &texturedCube[6]);

        int colorIndex = 0;
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        glColor4ub(colourCubeFaceColors[colorIndex], colourCubeFaceColors[colorIndex+1], colourCubeFaceColors[colorIndex+2], colourCubeFaceColors[colorIndex+3]);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &texturedCube[12]);

        glPopMatrix();
    }

    // GL teardown
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint pos = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    /*  
    int i = 0;
    for (NSDictionary *item in self.players) {

        IMPoint3D playerPos;

        playerPos.x = [[item objectForKey:@"posX"] floatValue];
        playerPos.z = [[item objectForKey:@"posZ"] floatValue];
        playerPos.y = 1.0f;

        if([self checkCollission:pos object:playerPos])
        {
            NSLog(@"FIRE I LOVE YOU MAN %i", i);
        }

    }
     */

    for (NSDictionary *item in self.players)
    {
        int x;
        int z;

        x =  [[item objectForKey:@"posX"] floatValue];
        z =  [[item objectForKey:@"posZ"] floatValue];

        IMPoint3D playerPos;
        playerPos.x = x;
        playerPos.z = z;
        playerPos.y = 1;

        CGPoint screenPositionOfThisCube  ; 
        screenPositionOfThisCube = [self getScreenCoorOfPoint:playerPos];


        #define TUNE 5
        CGRect fingerSquish = CGRectMake(
                                         screenPositionOfThisCube.x - TUNE,
                                         screenPositionOfThisCube.y - TUNE,
                                         TUNE * 2,
                                         TUNE * 2);

        // now check that the POINT OF THE TOUCH
        // is inside the rect fingerSquish

        if ( CGRectContainsPoint( fingerSquish, pos ) )
        {
            NSLog(@"WOOP");
            // YOU HAVE FOUND THE TOUCHED CUBEY.
            // YOU ARE DONE.  this item is the cube being touched.
            // make the cube change color or something to test it.
        }
    }



    //left
    if ( pos.x >= 35 && pos.x <= 80 && pos.y >= 0 && pos.y <= 40) {
        action = ActionTurnLeft;

    //right 
    } else if ( pos.x >= 35 && pos.x <= 80 && pos.y >= 80 && pos.y <= 120) {
        action = ActionTurnRight;

    //forward
    } else if ( pos.x >= 80 && pos.x <= 120 && pos.y >= 32 && pos.y <= 82) {
        action = ActionMoveForward;

    //back
    } else if ( pos.x >= 0 && pos.x <= 40 && pos.y >= 32 && pos.y <= 82) {
        action = ActionMoveBackward;
    }

} 

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    action = ActionNone; 
}

#define RAY_ITERATIONS 1000
#define COLLISION_RADIUS 0.1f

-(Boolean) checkCollission:(CGPoint)winPos object:(IMPoint3D) _object { 

    glGetFloatv( GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, __projection );  
    glGetFloatv( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, __modelview );
    glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, __viewport );

    winPos.y = (float)__viewport[3] - winPos.y;

    Point3D nearPoint;
    Point3D farPoint;
    Point3D rayVector;

    //Retreiving position projected on near plan
    gluUnProject( winPos.x, winPos.y , 0, __modelview, __projection, __viewport, &nearPoint.x, &nearPoint.y, &nearPoint.z);

    //Retreiving position projected on far plan
    gluUnProject( winPos.x, winPos.y,  1, __modelview, __projection, __viewport, &farPoint.x, &farPoint.y, &farPoint.z);

    //Processing ray vector
    rayVector.x = farPoint.x - nearPoint.x;
    rayVector.y = farPoint.y - nearPoint.y;
    rayVector.z = farPoint.z - nearPoint.z;

    float rayLength = sqrtf(POW2(rayVector.x) + POW2(rayVector.y) + POW2(rayVector.z));

    //normalizing ray vector
    rayVector.x /= rayLength;
    rayVector.y /= rayLength;
    rayVector.z /= rayLength;

    Point3D collisionPoint;
    Point3D objectCenter = {_object.x, _object.y, _object.z};

    //Iterating over ray vector to check collisions
    for(int i = 0; i < RAY_ITERATIONS; i++)
    {
        collisionPoint.x = rayVector.x * rayLength/RAY_ITERATIONS*i;
        collisionPoint.y = rayVector.y * rayLength/RAY_ITERATIONS*i;
        collisionPoint.z = rayVector.z * rayLength/RAY_ITERATIONS*i;

        //Checking collision 
        if([Tools poinSphereCollision:collisionPoint center:objectCenter radius:COLLISION_RADIUS])
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;   
} 


-(CGPoint)getScreenCoorOfPoint:(IMPoint3D)_point3D
{
    GLfloat     p[16];   // Where The 16 Doubles Of The Projection Matrix Are To Be Stored
    glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, p);                           // Retrieve The Projection Matrix
    /*
     Multiply M * point
     */
    GLfloat _p[] = {p[0]*_point3D.x +p[4]*_point3D.y +p[8]*_point3D.z + p[12],
        p[1]*_point3D.x +p[5]*_point3D.y +p[9]*_point3D.z + p[13],
        p[2]*_point3D.x +p[6]*_point3D.y +p[10]*_point3D.z+ p[14],
        p[3]*_point3D.x +p[7]*_point3D.y +p[11]*_point3D.z+ p[15]};
    /*
     divide by scale factor
     */
    CGPoint _p2D = {_p[0]/_p[3], _p[1]/_p[3]};
    /*
     get result in screen coordinates. In this case I'm in landscape mode
     */
    return (CGPoint) {_p2D.x*240.0f + 240.0f, (1.0f - _p2D.y) *160.0f};
}


- (void)handleTouches { 
    if (action != ActionNone) {
        GLfloat v[] = {center[0] - eye[0], center[1] - eye[1], center[2] - eye[2]}; 

        switch (action) {
            case ActionMoveForward: 

                eye[0] += v[0] * SPEED_MOVE;
                eye[2] += v[2] * SPEED_MOVE;
                center[0] += v[0] * SPEED_MOVE;
                center[2] += v[2] * SPEED_MOVE;

                if ((eye[2] > MapSizeZ || eye[0] > MapSizeX  || eye[2] < -MapSizeZ || eye[0] < -MapSizeX)  || [self checkCollisionWithX:eye[0] andWithZ:eye[2]]){

                    eye[0] -= v[0] * SPEED_MOVE; 
                    eye[2] -= v[2] * SPEED_MOVE;
                    center[0] -= v[0] * SPEED_MOVE;
                    center[2] -= v[2] * SPEED_MOVE;
                }

                break;
            case ActionMoveBackward: 

                eye[0] -= v[0] * SPEED_MOVE; 
                eye[2] -= v[2] * SPEED_MOVE;
                center[0] -= v[0] * SPEED_MOVE;
                center[2] -= v[2] * SPEED_MOVE;

                if ((eye[2] > MapSizeZ || eye[0] > MapSizeX  || eye[2] < -MapSizeZ || eye[0] < -MapSizeX) || [self checkCollisionWithX:eye[0] andWithZ:eye[2]] ){

                    eye[0] += v[0] * SPEED_MOVE;
                    eye[2] += v[2] * SPEED_MOVE;
                    center[0] += v[0] * SPEED_MOVE;
                    center[2] += v[2] * SPEED_MOVE;
                }
                break;

            case ActionTurnLeft: 
                center[0] = eye[0] + cos(-SPEED_TURN)*v[0] - sin(-SPEED_TURN)*v[2]; 
                center[2] = eye[2] + sin(-SPEED_TURN)*v[0] + cos(-SPEED_TURN)*v[2]; 
                rotation -=2.865;
                break;

            case ActionTurnRight: 
                center[0] = eye[0] + cos(SPEED_TURN)*v[0] - sin(SPEED_TURN)*v[2];
                center[2] = eye[2] + sin(SPEED_TURN)*v[0] + cos(SPEED_TURN)*v[2]; 
                rotation +=2.865;
                break;
        }

    }

}

- (void)loadTextures:(NSString *)textureName andWithIndex:(int)index { 

    // load image as a CG ref 
    CGImageRef textureImage = [UIImage imageNamed:textureName].CGImage;
    // if failed, bail
    if (!textureImage) { 
        NSLog(@"Error: failed to load texture"); 
        return;
    }


    // figure out the width and height
    int texWidth = CGImageGetWidth(textureImage); 
    int texHeight = CGImageGetHeight(textureImage);

    // alloc space for the texture
    GLubyte *textureData = (GLubyte *)malloc(texWidth * texHeight * 4);

    // create a CA context ref
    CGContextRef textureContext = CGBitmapContextCreate( 
                                                        textureData, texWidth, texHeight, 8, texWidth * 4, 
                                                        CGImageGetColorSpace(textureImage),
                                                        kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
                                                        );

    // draw the image to in-memory buffer
    CGContextDrawImage(textureContext, CGRectMake(0,0,texWidth,texHeight), textureImage);

    // done with context - release it
    CGContextRelease(textureContext); 

    // have GL create handle for our texture
    glGenTextures(1, &textures[index]); 

    // tell GL that the image is 2D
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[index]);

    // send our data down to GL, copy into graphics hardware
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

    // free our in-memory copy of the data
    free(textureData);

    // specify min/max filters
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // tell GL to turn on textures
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); 

}

- (void)updateCoords {

    self.players = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@UpdatePlayer.aspx?playerIndex=%@&posX=%f&posZ=%f&rotation=%f", baseURL, self.deviceID, eye[0], eye[2], rotation]]];

    [self updateData]; 
}

- (void)updateData {

    NSInvocationOperation *op = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateCoords) object:nil];
    [[(WorldAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sharedOperationQueue] addOperation:op];
    [op release];
}   

- (void)setupPlayer {

    // Device id
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    self.deviceID = [device uniqueIdentifier];

    NSDictionary *tempDict = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@GetPlayerPosition.aspx?playerIndex=%@", baseURL, self.deviceID]]] autorelease];
    eye[0] = [[tempDict objectForKey:@"posX"] floatValue];
    eye[2] = [[tempDict objectForKey:@"posZ"] floatValue]  ;
    rotation = [[tempDict objectForKey:@"rotation"] floatValue];
}

- (void)addScene {


    self.collisionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.collisionArray addObject:@"5,-4,4,4,1"];
    [self.collisionArray addObject:@"5, 4,4,4,1"];

    [self.collisionArray addObject:@"20,0,1,40,4"];
    [self.collisionArray addObject:@"-20,0,1,40,4"];

    [self.collisionArray addObject:@"0,-20,40,1,4"];
    [self.collisionArray addObject:@"0,20,40,1,4"];


}

- (void)loadTextureList {

    [self loadTextures:@"crate.png" andWithIndex:0];
    [self loadTextures:@"brick.jpg" andWithIndex:1];
    [self loadTextures:@"GrassTexture.png" andWithIndex:2];
    [self loadTextures:@"swtexnew.png" andWithIndex:3];

}

- (void)loadController {

    self.baseURL = @"http://burf2000.dyndns.org:90/Cubes/";

    //Controler
    UIImageView *joypadView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StoneCompass.png"]];
    joypadView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 120);
    [self.view addSubview:joypadView];
    [joypadView release];

}

- (BOOL)checkCollisionWithX:(float)x andWithZ:(float)z {

    for (NSString *coords in self.collisionArray) {

        NSArray *coordsArray = [coords componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        float x1 =  [[coordsArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue] -   ([[coordsArray objectAtIndex:2] floatValue] /2) ;
        float z1 =  [[coordsArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] -   ([[coordsArray objectAtIndex:3] floatValue] /2) ;
        float x2 =  [[coordsArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue] +   ([[coordsArray objectAtIndex:2] floatValue] /2) ;
        float z2 =  [[coordsArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] +   ([[coordsArray objectAtIndex:3] floatValue] /2) ;


        if ( x > x1 && x < x2  && z > z1  && z < z2 ) {

            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [deviceID release];
    [players release];
    [collisionArray release];
    [label release];
    [baseURL release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might look promising 
http://blog.nova-box.com/2010/05/iphone-ray-picking-glunproject-sample.html#comment-form

Comment: Yeah it does that, its a pitty you could not work out how to do this man, you put so much effort in to it.  I think I am going to have to pay someone or set a bounty

Answer (score 0):

In one of the posts linked to by Kos he argues against GL_SELECT for modern GL implementations, but maybe for OpenGL ES this kind of selection is what you want for this application - seems reasonable to do this within OpenGL? I read about it but haven't used it myself yet: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter13.html

Cheers, S

Comment: Not sure what you mean but glSelect is not available on the iphone