# Object selection with processing.js in 3d scenes

Tags: javascript, webgl, processing.js

I'm trying to do object selection in Processing.js on 3d renderings through webgl, but don't find any method that allows me to do it.

I know that in OpenGL you could change render mode to GL_SELECT, name and render each object, and when you're done find the name of the object that lies under the cursor.

This method would be fine for me if I could get the WebGL context out of the target canvas, but the getContext method returns null, for some weird reason.

Is there a way to get the rendering context from Processing.js and apply the method I mentioned, or is there a better approach in Processing.js itself?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access the rendering context from the instance as specified [here](http://processingjs.org/articles/RenderingModes.html):

From JavaScript:

```
var p = Processing.instances[0];
var context = p.externals.context;
var p2 = Processing.getInstanceById('canvas-id');
var p2Canvas = p2.externals.canvas;
```

From within Processing:

```
var currentContext = externals.context;
```

And then collision detection as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040616/opengl-gl-select-or-manual-collision-detection/4059685#4059685).